Unity shader - black dots visible at blending point of two textures
I'm trying to blend simple grass, rock, and snow textures as elevation increases on my procedurally generated mesh. All 3 textures have normal maps. At the point where the rock texture starts to blend into snow, there is a line of tiny black dots. Images:
image 1
image 2
The shader code for this part is:
            float snowLerped = saturate(InverseLerp(snowStart, snowFull, relHeight));
            float rockLerped = saturate(InverseLerp(rockStart, rockFull, relHeight));
            if (relHeight < snowStart) {
                outcol = col* (1 - rockLerped) + col3 * (rockLerped);
                o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_MainTexNM, IN.uv_MainTexNM * 10)) * 100 * (1 - rockLerped) + UnpackNormal(tex2D(_RockTexNM, IN.uv_RockTexNM * 10)) * (rockLerped);
            }
            else {
                outcol = col3 * (1 - snowLerped) + col2 * (snowLerped);
                o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_RockTexNM, IN.uv_RockTexNM * 10)) * (1 - snowLerped) + UnpackNormal(tex2D(_MountainTexNM, IN.uv_MountainTexNM * 10)) * (snowLerped);
            }

Note that relHeight is just the normalized y position of the fragment, from 0 (lowest point on the mesh) to 1 (highest point on the mesh). snowStart, snowFull, rockStart, and rockFull are the relative heights at which blending starts and ends for rock and snow.
I believe the issue stems from some discontinuity on the two sides of the if statement, but I am unable to find it. I would appreciate any help.
I changed the condition of the if statement to if (relHeight < snowStart - 0.05) { and the line of dots moved down. So I think there's some sort of discontinuity regarding the if statement, but I can't seem to find anything.
